# xPath of a jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

Given a jQuery element, how do I get its XPath .
I have an XPath function (somehow it doesn't work when I pass the jQuery element) .

Please check this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xAtx5/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `var a = document.getElementById('something');` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/pPd4b/ - it works.

PS. Or you can use for general cases:

```
var a = $('#something').get(0);
```

Comment: great , it works .. how do I convert a jQuery element into a normal non Jquery element

Comment: @SAnandNarayan: Either `$x.get(0)` or `$x[0]` will unwrap the jQuery stuff and leave you with a plain old DOM element.